# How to group by overlapping one-hot encoded categorical data in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset of games with critic scores and categorical data of whether the game was featured in a publication - take the following as a simplified version of the dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'titleName': ['game_A', 'game_B', 'game_C', 'game_D'],
    'reviewScore': [88.1, 70.3, 91.3, 66.1],
    'mediaAppearances': [['Pub_A', 'Pub_C'], ['Pub_B'], ['Pub_B', 'Pub_C'], ['Pub_A', 'Pub_B', 'Pub_C']]}
)
```

mediaAppearances is a categorical feature with multiple potential values for any record - it captures whether the game appeared in a given Publisher's reporting. The feature is one-hot encoded to produce discrete boolean columns for each Publisher (i.e. 'True' if the game appeared on that Publisher, 'False' if it didn't):

```
final_df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['mediaAppearances'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).groupby(level=0).sum()], axis=1)
```

This produces the following DataFrame:

| titleName | reviewScore | mediaAppearances | Pub_A | Pub_B | Pub_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| game_A | 88.1 | "Pub_A, Pub_C" | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| game_B | 70.3 | "Pub_B" | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| game_C | 91.3 | "Pub_B, Pub_C" | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| game_D | 66.1 | "Pub_A, Pub_B, Pub_C" | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I want to group the DataFrame by each Publisher, so I can analyze reviewScore for games that were featured by a specific Publisher. The end result should have three groups (where Pub_n equals True) where reviewScore can be further aggregated / analyzed.

I can independently filter the Data Frame by each unique Publisher as follows:

```
for publisher in ['Pub_A', 'Pub_B', 'Pub_C']:
    _mean = final_df[final_df[publisher] == True]['reviewScore'].mean()
    print(f"Mean reviewScore for games appearing in {publisher}: {_mean:.1f}")
```

Output:

```
Mean reviewScore for games appearing in Pub_A: 77.1  
Mean reviewScore for games appearing in Pub_B: 75.9  
Mean reviewScore for games appearing in Pub_C: 81.8
```

This works fine for calculating single summary stats; however, the workflow is burdensome when attempting to use custom aggregation functions, analyze multiple summary stats at once (e.g. with pandas' describe function), or quickly switch between grouping by Publisher vs. other dataset variables.

Ideally, I'd be able to use Pandas' standard groupby and aggregate syntax; however, since Publisher values are not exclusive after one-hot encoding the mediaAppearance variable, grouping by the Publisher columns yields an unwieldy matrix with all unique True/False combinations

```
final_df.groupby(['Pub_A', 'Pub_B', 'Pub_C']).describe().reset_index()
```

Output:

| Pub_A | Pub_B | Pub_C | count | mean | std | min | 25% | 50% | 75% | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1.0 | 70.3 | NaN | 70.3 | 70.3 | 70.3 | 70.3 | 70.3 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1.0 | 91.3 | NaN | 91.3 | 91.3 | 91.3 | 91.3 | 91.3 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1.0 | 88.1 | NaN | 88.1 | 88.1 | 88.1 | 88.1 | 88.1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1.0 | 66.1 | NaN | 66.1 | 66.1 | 66.1 | 66.1 | 66.1 |

Is there a groupBy query that will produce a single grouped DataFrame that allows application of aggregation functions to the entire frame vs. requiring aggregation of individually filtered data frames? For example, is there a query that would produce the following for pandas builtin describe function?

| Publiser | count | mean | std | min | 25% | 50% | 75% | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pub_A | 2.0 | 77.1 | 15.6 | 66.1 | 71.6 | 77.1 | 82.6 | 88.1 |
| Pub_B | 3.0 | 75.9 | 13.5 | 66.1 | 68.2 | 70.3 | 80.8 | 91.3 |
| Pub_C | 3.0 | 81.8 | 13.7 | 66.1 | 77.1 | 88.1 | 89.7 | 91.3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using groupby, but this alternative method might help.

In the one-hot encoded columns you can change the "1" by the reviewScore and remove the "0".
Based on your version of final_df:

Input:

```
final_df_2 = final_df.copy()
pub_list = ['Pub_A', 'Pub_B', 'Pub_C']

final_df_2[pub_list] = final_df_2[pub_list].replace(0, np.NAN)

for pub_n in pub_list:
    final_df_2[pub_n] = final_df_2[pub_n] * final_df_2['reviewScore']

final_df_2
```

Output:

```
    titleName   reviewScore mediaAppearances       Pub_A    Pub_B   Pub_C
0   game_A      88.10       [Pub_A, Pub_C]         88.10    NaN     88.10
1   game_B      70.30       [Pub_B]                NaN      70.30   NaN
2   game_C      91.30       [Pub_B, Pub_C]         NaN      91.30   91.30
3   game_D      66.10       [Pub_A, Pub_B, Pub_C]  66.10    66.10   66.10
```

And then use describe:

Input:

```
final_df_2.describe()
```

Output:

```
        reviewScore Pub_A   Pub_B   Pub_C
count   4.00        2.00    3.00    3.00
mean    78.95       77.10   75.90   81.83
std     12.60       15.56   13.50   13.72
min     66.10       66.10   66.10   66.10
25%     69.25       71.60   68.20   77.10
50%     79.20       77.10   70.30   88.10
75%     88.90       82.60   80.80   89.70
max     91.30       88.10   91.30   91.30
```

Comment: I think this is a good approach - it allows most summary stats to be easily calc'd, and custom aggregation functions can be applied without looping. I'm going to wait to see if there is a method that utilized groupBy before marking this as the answer, since although this works for my use case, I can see ways this may fall short for other situations with one-hot encoded data.